# Comment / documentation as metadata

Tags: python, metadata

If I type-annotate my code properly, and use something like Pylance in my IDE, when I hover over a method or function I get helpful information about that code's 'signature': the variables it expects, their types, and what I can expect from that code in terms of a response. All that is great, and I have come to rely on it in my daily coding activities.

Anyway, I was reviewing some old code of mine, and was trying to make sense of it after 18+ months (I'm sure I'm alone in that, right? lol). And although I had commented the code in question back then, looking at it now I found the comments to actually clutter things up, instead of being very helpful.

So it got me to thinking: what if there were some sort of plugin or code-assistant library that, when I hovered over a section of code, not only gave me the code's signature/type annotation info, but also gave me the documentation for that particular section? I could potentially make the comments much longer and clearer without having to worry about code bloat, or its visual impact.

### tldr;

***is there a way to make my comments be metadata instead of having to be embedded in the code itself?***

Comment: Are you talking about `""" These comments """` that are used on the line after a function is made? Or are you talking about preprogramming the syntax highlighter to give one of these comments without having to explicitly write it?

Comment: Most decent text editors allow you to "fold" or "collapse" sections of a file so that they aren't obtrusive while trying to read the rest of the file. Only when you need to see the comments do you "unfold" or "expand" that section to read its contents.

Comment: Both VS Code and PyCharm show class and function/method docstrings (comments immediately inside the definition of the class/function/method that are surrounded by 3x `"` or `'`, though `"` is preferred via [PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)) by default.  Comments using `#` generally are not handled that way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies so far. I guess I wasn't all that clear. I was thinking of a situation where you could develop all your code's documentation and have it hosted in the cloud, and then in your IDE you could hover over the various sections and have the relevant sections appear in the IDE, without the comments having to be there in the code itself. The benefits I can see right now are: a proper environment to develop and house documentation; cleaner looking code. I'm sure there are drawbacks as well.